# Saving permission changes for device

Tags: linux, permissions, reboot, suse

I have installed a driver on SUSE, and changed permissions for it (`/dev/name`) with the `chgrp` command.

However after rebooting my computer the change is lost. How can I save the permissions for the device?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [write a udev rule](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) to run an external program to change ownership of the device node.