# Losing permissions changes after reboot

Tags: linux, file-permissions, reboot, suse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Saving permission changes for device.](https://superuser.com/questions/217061/saving-permission-changes-for-device)

Hi.

I have installed a driver on my Suse, and changed the permissions for him- /dev/name, with chgrp command.

but after rebooting my computer- the change was lost. What should I do?

Thanks in advance,

Sara

Comment: This question is more appropriate for superuser (or maybe server fault) rather than stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a udev rule to run an external program to change ownership of the device node.

Comment: Can you explain more, please?

Comment: http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html

Comment: the /etc/udev/rules.d/50-udev.rules file doesn't exist. is it a problem?