# Permanently changing permission of device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, ubuntu-10.10, chmod

My question is related to a [Saving permission changes for device](https://superuser.com/questions/217061/saving-permission-changes-for-device) question except it is for Ubuntu 10.10: Maverick.

I just setup a FireWire audio interface. Everything works fine, except for I need rw-rw-rw- permissions on /dev/fw0. I can always `sudo chmod 666 /dev/fw0` just before setting the thing up, but then it will be gone on the next rebooting.

The solution to modify `/etc/udev/rules.d/020-permissions.rules` (which is for Ubuntu Breezy) doesn't go well for Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick because there is no **/etc/udev/rules.d** directory.

What should i do in order for /dev/fw0 to come up with 666 permissions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reloading udev rules fails](http://superuser.com/questions/311940/reloading-udev-rules-fails)